# when i using the HTML Drag and Drop API , draggable didn't work

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```js
var dragged

    document.addEventListener("drag", function (event) {
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
      dragged = event.target
      event.target.style.opacity = .5
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragend", function (event) {
      event.target.style.opacity = ""
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragenter", function (event) {
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = "purple"
      }

    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragleave", function (event) {
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = ""
      }

    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = ""
        dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged)
        event.target.appendChild(dragged)
      }

    }, false)
```

```css
   #draggable {
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background: white;
    }

    .dropzone {
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
      background: blueviolet;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="dropzone ">
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
      this is draggable
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
```

i want to the text into other div containers.
[drag text into other div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JaL2.png)

[drag text into other div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMll7.png)

but i find i can drag div container.just like this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTSH5.png)

although set draggable = 'false',i still  can drag div container.

```
<div class="dropzone " draggable="false">
<div id="draggable" draggable="true"ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
    this is draggable
</div>
</div><div class="dropzone" draggable="false">
</div><div class="dropzone" draggable="false">
</div><div class="dropzone" draggable="false"></div>
```

i use  chrome and i can't see any error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `user-select: none;` in `.dropzone` class. The problem was when you drag .dropzone first time, it was selecting the .dropzone and the text which is drag-able. 
With the use of `user-select: none;` on `.dropzone`, it will not select dropzone div.

Give it a try.

```js
var dragged

    document.addEventListener("drag", function (event) {
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
      dragged = event.target
      event.target.style.opacity = .5
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragend", function (event) {
      event.target.style.opacity = ""
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragenter", function (event) {
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = "purple"
      }

    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("dragleave", function (event) {
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = ""
      }

    }, false)

    document.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = ""
        dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged)
        event.target.appendChild(dragged)
      }

    }, false)
```

```css
#draggable {
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background: white;
    }

    .dropzone {
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
      background: blueviolet;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropzone ">
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
      this is draggable
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
```